# My .xlsx file from Pandas does not print date column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, xlsx, pandas-datareader

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date

df = pd.read_excel('../Pandas_CoalPublic/employee.xlsx', date_format='dd/mm/yyyy')

#print(df)
#print(df.dtypes)

Hiring_Data = df[df['hire_date'] > '01-01-2007']
Hiring_Data.to_excel('Hiring_Data.xlsx')
print(Hiring_Data)
```

Comment: If I print the data in console, it gives me proper result. But if I export the data to xlsx file it gives ####### in the date column.

Comment: This is the data from console printed

Comment: emp_id first_name   last_name  hire_date
4      104      Bruce       Ernst 2007-05-21
7      107      Diana     Lorentz 2007-02-07
13     113       Luis        Popp 2007-12-07
19     119      Karen  Colmenares 2007-08-10

Comment: emp_id first_name last_name hire_date
4 104 Bruce Ernst 2007-05-21 00:00:00
7 107 Diana Lorentz 2007-02-07 00:00:00
13 113 Luis Popp 2007-12-07 00:00:00
19 119 Karen Colmenares 2007-08-10 00:00:00

Comment: `#####` did you try expanding the column ? or manually changing the excel datatype? can you print(df.dtypes)